# Why Autoreload throw error on class import?

Tags: python-3.x, class, ipython, spyder

When I make simple class:

```
class Two:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value=2
```

and then I have a different file to import this class:

```
from testclass import Two

x=1
y=Two().value

print("x=",x," and y=",y)
```

Then, whenever I change anything in file testclass, I get following error:

> Reloaded modules: testclass x= 1  and y= 2 [autoreload of testclass
>   failed: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py",
>   line 245, in check
>       superreload(m, reload, self.old_objects)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py",
>   line 450, in superreload
>       update_generic(old_obj, new_obj)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py",
>   line 387, in update_generic
>       update(a, b)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py",
>   line 357, in update_class
>       update_instances(old, new)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py",
>   line 312, in update_instances
>       update_instances(old, new, obj.**dict**, visited)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py",
>   line 317, in update_instances
>       update_instances(old, new, obj, visited)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py",
>   line 312, in update_instances
>       update_instances(old, new, obj.**dict**, visited)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py",
>   line 312, in update_instances
>       update_instances(old, new, obj.**dict**, visited)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py",
>   line 317, in update_instances
>       update_instances(old, new, obj, visited)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py",
>   line 312, in update_instances
>       update_instances(old, new, obj.**dict**, visited) NotImplementedError: Operator 'getitem' is not supported on this
>   expression ]

When I run it second time, without changing anything I get
x= 1  and y= 2

So am I doing anything wrong or why auto-reload throw that error when I modify testclass?

Comment: Please updayte to the latest IPython version. This should be fixed in that version.

Comment: I am using anaconda navigator and it says that i have newest version of IPython console, namely version 7.8.0

Comment: That mean the problem is still not solved for me.

Comment: The latest version (as of today) is IPython 7.10.1